# MSBuild WCF Options

Tags: wcf, msbuild, svcutil.exe

I think I need to use custom 'svcutil' options to generate a WCF client.  I know that I can provide a custom pre-build Event in my project file and apply the svcutil command line there.

However I'm wondering if there's any documentation on what overridable rules or targets exist in MSBuild that can be used to override the default command-line parameters for WCF's SvcUtil in VS 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Project files tend to be mostly item groups. If you look in the Fmk directory you'll see the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file. This [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/msbuild/modifyingthevsbuildprocess/) explains more about it.

I would tend to add to the CompileDependsOn property (like in the article actually :-)